# Why cannot people upvote my questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

I was once banned from Stack Overflow since I was a newbie and removed several questions of mine. After a while the ban was lifted. I asked another question that got one upvote, and I got banned again.

I then read about being banned and noticed that if I start being productive on Stack Overflow, the ban will be lifted. I tried to be really productive and I managed to rank up into the top 0.95% this month. I'm still banned and my (only) four questions weren't upvoted since a long time.

Today a friend of mine told me that he did want to upvote my question (about [Microsoft Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word)), but the score didn't go up. I checked and noticed I have gotten the point for upvoting, but the question "vote" number hasn't changed.

Does it mean that I am banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow forever?

This question is not about friends upvoting me. I don't care about points. What I care about is again being able to ask questions. If I'm banned and my questions cannot be upvoted, how can I get out of the ban?

Comment: There was a serial voting reversed two days ago.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah I gained and lost a bunch of scores. but it didn't affect my total points and other answers in general

Comment: @gnat: This is not about serial voting, this is about a perceived ban on getting voted on.

Comment: Guys, stop robo-close-voting this. The dupe target doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus heh, not my first experience with downvotes, I get one downvote, it'll be like domino without them trying to reading the "edit" or comments or even the whole question  .

Comment: he war referring to close votes not the downvotes. You should also see downvotes differently here on meta. It's more of a "disagreement" here.

Comment: @Hayt well not much of a difference. I was talking about  the domino-like voting. We see it in SO downvoting, now we saw it in meta closing.

Comment: @gnat where is "my questions cannot be upvoted" mentioned in that link ?

Comment: see the sections "What can I do to release the ban?" - it covers what you ask about

Comment: @gnat how is `my question cannot be upvoted` similar to `down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others.` ?

Comment: A bit of a silly question.... but does your friend have enough rep to upvote?

Comment: @Patrice yes he does

Comment: The given close-reason/duplicate question of the recent closure does not apply. This question deals with voting by a friend merely as a by product and instead is focused on some bug/functionality of SO foremost. That should be kind of obvious.

Answer (score 21):

## There is no such thing as a "vote ban" on SO.

It does not exist. The only way SO can keep you from voting, is by banning you completely.

---

However, it does look like you lost 150 rep two days ago, because some [serial voting was reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed):

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a variety of reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge. No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

Comment: yeah I noticed I gained like 170 points and lost a bunch of scores (150) next day. but it didn't affect my total points and other answers in general. Does it affect the ban-length?

Comment: Those votes have no effect on your question-ban.

Comment: Do they have effects on my "being upvoted" ban ?

Comment: Like I said, there is no such ban. It does not exist.

Comment: Because I mean, why shouldn't my question be upvoted while I get points for the upvotes? I mean if I'm not going to get something, shouldn't it be the points and not the upvotes since upvotes are supposed to lift the ban? like this : 
I'm banned from asking ->  people upvoate my question -> I don't get point instead my question will "generate traffic" -> the ban will be eventually lifted and I'll again get points for upvotes 

not like this : 
I'm banned from asking ->  people upvoate my question -> I get point and not upvote -> banned for ever

Comment: But a friend of mine told me now that he wanted to upvoate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850310/word-2013-footnote-custom-balance) question, I got 5 points for the upvoate. but the upvote number is still 2

Comment: @Yugi if you are organizing voting ring to upvote your posts (even if it consist only from "one friend of mine") you are heading toward total ban...

Comment: @Yugi: If your friend was the one that serially voted on your post, there may well have been some caching inconsistencies between the vote count he sees, and the actual vote count on the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus no he wasn't. that was few days ago and I heard about this problem like 30minutes ago from him

Comment: Maybe he only noticed it just now.

Comment: @Cerbrus noticed what? I think you can see in my profile that I got +5  
for this question "Word 2013 - footnote custom balance?". But the vote number is still the same

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If I wanted to do so, I wouldn't put like 3 hours a day answering questions for lifting the ban

Comment: @Yugi: There really isn't anything special going on with that question. It was [upvoted twice and downvoted once](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35850310/timeline). That's it. Note that we can't see how much time you spend on SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry for asking many questions, but isn't the last event for 7 hours ago? but as I said the upvote (that was reversed) happened 51 mins ago. So it means it is not even logged there.

Comment: Votes are compiled in a "daily summary", which is timestamped with the start of the day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126496/discussion-between-yugi-and-cerbrus).

Comment: "A friend of mine told me now" lol

Comment: @Pekka웃 so what's the worst case? I am banned because I was new to the SO and deleted couple of questions a year ago(!) , I was desperate and asked a friend to upvote a question of mine. so what even if it's so?

Answer (score -13):

This is something Stack Exchange engineers might want to look into. When you click on upvote the score should definitely increase by one unless maybe at the same time someone else downvoted (not sure how the display reacts then). This is usually relatively unlikely unless there is much voting going on. The only other possibility is that the vote reversal script detecting serial upvotings kicked in.

If you are still convinced that this is a technical problem, your friend, who experienced the effect, should contact Stack Exchange customer support and explain the problem.

Also please be aware, that your friend should only upvote your questions if he genuinely finds them interesting. If he does so more often, he might trigger a serial voting reversal action which is there to prevent abuse and which might look like what you are seeing here.

Comment: Moderators won't be able to do much here. We can't see votes, nor can we correct them. At best, you could contact SE directly, but I'm guessing that this is a non-issue and is merely a result of the vote invalidation from the script.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for the comment. I didn't know what moderators can see and what they can't see in this regard. The vote invalidation from the script sounds very likely to me too although the OP claimed it is unrelated. But probably that's the solution.